# AngularJS bolding statements in search box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and am wondering how to bold statements that I'm searching for in the page. I'm using the filter method to filter a table, but I'd like to bold the filtered statements as well. For example, if I'm searching for

```
test
```

I'd like the following to be bolded:

```
this is a <b>test</b>
etc
```

Here's my controller code:

```
function PhoneListCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/text.json').success(function(data){
      $scope.phones = data;
  });

  $scope.hello = "Hello, World";
  $scope.orderProp = 'age';
  $scope.query = "";
  //$scope.query

  $scope.smart_filter = function(item){
      item = item.snippet;
      var query_words = $scope.query.split(" ");

      return query_words.every(function(word){return item.indexOf(word) != -1})
  };

  $scope.test = function(item){
      return "<b>" + item + "</b>";
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Highlight module of [Angular UI-Utils](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/). It does precisely what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to "unsafe bind" your text:

```
<span ng-html-bind-unsafe="textWithMarkup"></span>
```